# What routes are there for citizens to attempt to change a law in Sweden?

Tags: legislature, sweden, government, legislative-drafting

If a citizen wished to have a change to a law voted upon by the government, in Sweden, how should they get into contact with lawmakers to discuss the idea, analyze the current law, provide argumentation for what should be changed and why, draft the new law, and submit it for voting?

Comment: "Draft the new law, and submit it for voting" in almost all democracies is restricted to  elected officials. Equally common, citizens have the right to petition those elected officials. I'll leave the precise Swedish procedure for someone else to answer.

Comment: @MSalters I dunno. "We've got to pass the law to find out what's in it," and similar incidents show that's definitely not the case for America!

Comment: This really should be migrated to Politics.SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is purely about the politics of persuading lawmakers to enact legislation.